# Prononciation : « air » vs « aire »

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, e-caduc

Dans un commentaire d'Air Canada dans [cette vidéo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgDizh4DMno):

> Ces gestes vont clairement à l'encontre de nos procédures lorsque des bagages sont enregistrés à la porte embarquement: ces procédures stipulent que les bagages doivent être descendu à la main jusqu'à  l'**aire** de circulation.

Cette question me mène à vérifier la prononciation de [*aire*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/aire/1945?q=aire#1944), vis-à-vis de [celle de *air*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/air/1940?q=air#1941). 
À mes oreilles, *aire* se prononce avec un *r* percutant et vigoureux. Par contre, concernant *air*, je n'entends qu'une trace du *r*. Cette différence est-elle marquée ?

Comment: Le wijktionnaire donne la prononciation des mots. Avec l'API tu peux comparer les signes et voir que ce sont les mêmes. [air](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/air) et [aire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aire) : /ɛʁ/ .

Comment: "...les bagages doivent être descendus à la main..." un s à descendus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'après Wikipédia à [E caduc](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc):

> Les régions où la langue d'oc est parlée prononcent plus fortement l'e caduc que celles du Nord à cause de la conservation de l'accent tonique dans ces régions. Ainsi, le Nord de la France prononce le mot *poêle* /pwal/, sans le distinguer phonétiquement du mot *poil*. Au contraire, les Occitans prononcent /ˈpwa.lə/.

Il s'agit exactement du même genre de distinction pour *air* (ɛʁ) et *aire* (ɛʁə). Le son noté *ə* en fin de mot<sup>1</sup>, qui correspond à la présence d'un *e* à l'écrit, est un son voyelle neutre qui a généralement pour effet de prolonger la consonne ou la voyelle qu'il suit. Cela explique ton expérience.

—
<sup>1. Note : le Wiktionnaire a choisi de ne pas ajouter ces *ə* en fin de mot dans les prononciations. Je [le cite](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aide:Prononciations): « La notation phonologique (entre //) transcrit le discours considéré comme standard (c’est-à-dire de registre de langue courant — ni populaire, ni soigné —, et entendu en milieu urbain d’Île-de-France) : ainsi, les e caducs non prononcés ne sont pas retranscrits. À l’inverse, la notation phonétique (entre []) peut les faire apparaitre ou disparaitre, suivant le registre de langue utilisé et la région du locuteur. », ce qui à vrai dire est faux car le Wiktionnaire reporte d'autres distinctions que les parisiens (de souche) ne font pas, comme celle entre *brin* et *brun*.</sup>

Comment: Si tu me demandais personnellement je dirais que la prononciation des deux mots par des gens du sud n'a rien à voir. Mais je me suis habitué à ce que les gens du nord ne fassent pas la différence. Enfin… récemment quelqu'un me parlait *du « mer »* sans plus de contexte, et j'ai quand même mis quelque temps à faire le lien avec le *maire*.

Comment: Dans le midi (plutôt la Gascogne, le Sud-Ouest) on prononce "touteu les lettreu" [ -*eu* étant une translittération du `ə`]

Comment: Dans l'nord et l'est on a pas l'temps d'les prononcer, on taf' trop ;-)