# Facteurs dans la prononciation de "but"

Tags: prononciation

C'est en écoutant « Le jour où j'arrêterai l'rap » de Kery James que, dans [la séquence qui commence vers 0:44](https://youtu.be/RHtVhEMmHXs?t=44), j'ai entendu pour la première fois la prononciation /byt/ pour *but*. Eh bien, lorsque j'ai consulté [le dictionnaire](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/but) j'ai trouvé ce /t/ facultatif à la fin.

Dans ce cas il le fait sans doute pour que ça rime avec « brute » et « brut » (je suis surpris par la prononciation de ce dernier aussi). Mais en général, comment saurais-je quelle prononciation employer ?

- Variation libre ?
- Âge ? Registre ? Région géographique ?
- Un contexte particulier phonologique ?
- Qqch d'autre ?

Comment: En quoi la prononciation de brut est surprenante? Je n'ai pas entendu la chanson mais brut se prononce toujours comme brute.

Comment: @Exocytosis D'accord, mais je voulais dire que comme apprenant, moi je m'attendrais à une consonne finale silencieuse en voyant l'orthographe.

Comment: Ah d'accord, merci de l'explication, je pensais que vous entendiez d'habitude une autre prononciation.

Comment: En français, le seul contexte où j'entends *but* sans le *t* c'est par des commentateurs de football. Juste les commentateurs hein, tous les autres gens qui parlent de foot prononcent le *t*. Et c'est pareil dans les autres contextes ("*mon but dans la vie*", "*un but à atteindre*", ...) on prononce quasiment toujours le *t*.

Comment: En ce qui concerne le registre, ne pas prononcer le *t* fait plus soutenu.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat En français « métropolitain » et pas au Québec où c'est la norme et où l'impression est inversée. La réponse de jlliagre fait amplement état de ce dont tu parles, rendant ton commentaire essentiellement incomplet superflu de surcroît... N'hésite pas à rédiger une réponse. Les commentaires sous les questions n'ont pas vocation à surclasser les réponses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La tendance générale est souvent à l'amuïssement mais il y a de nombreuses exceptions, dont *but* :

> Les consonnes finales en latin ou devenues finales par la dispariton
>   de la syllabe finale se sont généralement maintenues en anc. fr., puis
>   se sont souvent amuïes par la suite.
>
> Les exceptions sont nombreuses. En particulier, des consonnes qui
>   n'étaient plus que graphiques s'articulent de nouveau dans des
>   monosyllabes, soumis plus que les autres mots à des homophonies
>   gênantes : [ on donne des exemples de concurrences contemporaines...
>   *cric, but* et *mœurs* ].[...].
>   
>   Les consonnes finales muettes reparaissent dans les liaisons [...].
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>,
>   §78 ]

Au Québec, d'après mon expérience, la situation est comparable pour *cric*, \kʁik\, et *moeurs*, \mœʁs\, mais pas pour ***but*** que l'on [prononce](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Prononciation) systématiquement \by\ et où faire entendre la consonne finale est inusité et sera associé au français européen (la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4029) dit qu'on *peut* prononcer des deux manières). On prononce la consonne finale dans *brut* \bʁyt\ ; je ne sais pas si le mot correspond au prototype de transformation présenté au LBU.

---

Donc oui, variation, région et contexte (liaison, origine du mot) selon la situation.

Comment: Outrecuidant, ou seulement « imbu » ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bien bu ;) Bof mon propos se veut une réaction à une réponse, je ne pense pas ça généralement. Il y a une question de délicatesse linguistique quand on parle de ses perceptions quoique la différence fait réagir, c'est bien normal.

Comment: Beaucoup de renseignements utiles et intéressants dans ce fil, donc c'est difficile de choisir la réponse la plus appropriée, mais je trouve la vôtre équilibrée. La remarque de Grevisse sur la monosyllabicité des exceptions à la règle générale est très intéressante. Merci !

Comment: Outrecuidance itou à la BDL, qui donne droit de cité au T final prononcé de *but* (une prononciation parfaitement étrangère au Québec, à l'exception de quelques dessins animés idiots) et ne mentionne pas même celui de *lit* (pourtant omniprésent au Québec). On y agit comme si les défauts des autres étaient des particularités, et que nos particularités étaient des aberrations, cancers, idioties. Aplaventrisme.

Comment: @Montéedelait Juste pour être clair, c'était moi qui avait qualifié d'outrecuidant le parler dans une [version précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/36232/1) de la réponse et Stéphane faisait une blague avec ça, il ne qualifiait pas la réponse... ouais _lit_ un bon point. La BDL veut être régulière et s'il y a concurrence entre les prononciations c'est qu'on peut prononcer des deux manières, mais ne pas indiquer ce qui s'avère clairement la norme au Québec est à mon avis une erreur, ils auraient dû dire qu'on y disait \by\...

Comment: Je fais aussi des blagues, en y ajoutant néanmoins parfois un peu de mes frustrations. Une thérapie par le ridicule face à des situations pour lesquelles jamais ne s’établira de consensus. Mieux vaut en rire qu’en pleurer, que je me dis. Me restera à apprendre à ne pas être aussi chiche sur l’élément humoristique, peut-être...

Comment: Incidentally, now having asked half a dozen Francophones of my acquaintance here in Ontario, and getting /by/ from all of them on a blind reading, I feel like my not having heard it before Kery James fits well with the pattern and with the observations made in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

La prononciation muette fait snob. Le T final est en général prononcé, en tout cas en France, par la plupart des gens.

Cela ne concerne que « but » le synonyme d'objectif, et c'est ce mot qui est employé par l'artiste dans la vidéo (j'ai vérifié). Je confirme ici aussi que brut se prononce toujours comme brute, jamais d'exception.

Mais je confirme aussi ce qu'écrit hoplageiss concernant les accords de verbes se terminant en « ut », dont on ne prononce le T final que dans les liaisons. À noter que « ut », le synonyme de do la note musicale, se prononce toujours avec le T final, comme dans une « hutte ».

Comment: Bien d'accord, sauf sur le fait que *ut* [yt] se prononce comme *hutte* ['ytə] ;-) (et pareil pour *brut* et *brute*)

Comment: @Stéphane: Je ne sais pas d'où vous tirez cette information, mais le TLFI (atilf.atilf.fr) donne un autre avis sur ce sujet, sans parler du fait que je n'ai jamais entendu pareille prononciation de « hutte » en France, sauf chez ceux généralisant la prononciation du  E muet pour des raisons régionales ou personnelles. Je cite le TLFI:  HUTTE, subst. fém. (...) Prononc. et Orth. : [yt] init. asp. Att. ds Ac. dep. 1694. Homon. ut (et rien d'autre)

Comment: [E caduc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc), il y a une section qui parle de ça. Oui je faisais référence à une prononciation régionale (environ une moitié de la France métropolitaine quand même). Je me rappelle aussi avoir évoqué ça ailleurs plusieurs fois, par exemple [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/prononciation-air-vs-aire).

Answer (score 3):

Lorsqu'il s'agit du verbe boire à la 3e personne du singulier du passé simple (il but) on ne prononce pas le T final.
Lorsqu'il s'agit du nom masculin, on prononce généralement le T final.

Answer (score 3):

La prononciation du *T* de *but* varie, en France, suivant le contexte :

- En fin de phrase, le *T* est quasiment toujours prononcé : *Il erre sans but* /sɑ̃byt/.
- Dans certaines expressions, le *T* est souvent omis à l'oral : *Association sans but lucratif* /sɑ̃bylykratif/
- Dans d'autres, il est toujours réalisé : *de but en blanc*.

Dans le langage sportif, on observe quelques cas particuliers :

- *Un but à zéro.*  - les deux formes sont courantes : /œ̃byazero/ /œ̃bytazero/
- *Deux buts.* - le *T* est le plus souvent prononcé : /døbyt/, mais on entend aussi /døby/
- *Deux buts à zéro.* - le *T* est parfois prononcé, le *S* jamais : /døbytazero/
  /døby azero/
- *Deux buts à un.* - le *T* n'est pas prononcé mais la liaison est faite : /døbyzaœ̃/

Answer (score 2):

Je crois qu'il faut se rendre à l'évidence dont fait part le TLFi.

> PRONONC. ET ORTH. : [by] ou [byt]. Transcr. [by] dans Pt ROB. ainsi que dans NOD. 1844, LITTRÉ et DG. Les 2 transcr. dans PASSY 1914, BARBEAU-RODHE 1930, DUB., Pt Lar. 1968 et WARN. 1968. dans Lar. Lang. fr. [by] et [byt] devant voyelle. Cf. ROUSS.-LACL. 1927, p. 171 : ,,On hésite pour un certain nombre de mots : fa(t), bu(t), ne(t), c'est un fai(t).'L'ensemble des ouvrages note comme NYROP Phonét. 1951, § 87 et 260 : ,,But se prononce tantôt [by] (prononciation officielle), tantôt [byt]. On a surtout tendance à faire entendre le t quand le mot est final, [devant voyelle, notamment dans les locutions but à but et de but en blanc] ou marqué par l'emphase : voilà mon but [byt]; mais le but [by] principal.' FOUCHÉ Prononc. 1959, p. 406, signale que l'on prononce toujours [byt] dans le lang. sportif. BUBEN 1935, § 220, explique la restitution du t final par l'influence du fém. butte ,,avec lequel but était quelquefois confondu'. Notons que l'orth. butte l'emporte au XIXe et au XXe s. dans l'expr. être en but(t)e à. LITTRÉ s'élève contre la prononc. [byt] même en finale : ,,Cela ne vaut rien et est un effet de la tendance vicieuse (...) à faire sonner les consonnes. 'MART. Comment prononce 1913, p. 329, dit qu'on prononce toujours [by] à Paris et que la prononc. [byt] est provinciale. Pour G. STRAKA, La Prononc. parisienne dans B. de la Faculté des Lettres de Strasbourg, 1952, p. 26 et 27, les hésitations du bon usage quant à la prononc. de la consonne finale ,,sont compréhensibles et on aurait tort de les réprouver; le jour viendra (...) où l'un des deux doublets l'emportera; ce sera sans doute celui qui, d'accord avec la tendance phonétique générale, représente une innovation' (prononc. [byt]). Enq. : /byt/.

Il a existé des variations régionales dont il reste vraisemblablement  toujours des traces substantielles et il a existé des variations dues au contexte phonologique et celles-ci ont possiblement  laissé des séquelles.

J'ai eu l'occasion d'entendre une fois dans ma vie la prononciation « [by] », dans la bouche d'un commentateur sportif (en contradiction avec l'affirmation faite ci-dessus), et j'en ai été  dérangé suffisamment en cela que le contexte indiquait clairement qu'il ne d'agissait pas d'un autre mot que « but »,  que je n'avais jamais jusque là entendu prononcé autrement que « [byt] ». 
Je pense, malgré l'existence de règles phonologiques, parce qu'elles ne peuvent être appliquées que par très peu d'utilisateurs du français, qu'il n'y a aucun problème à utiliser uniquement la prononciation « [byt] », quel que soit le contexte ; il est temps il me semble que se réalise la prophétie que l'on peut lire dans la fin du paragraphe  dupliqué ci-dessus sur la prononciation et l'orthographe. Je ne pourrais pas en dire autant pour le mot « fait », qui est mentionné dans ce paragraphe : pour ce mot-ci on est habitué à entendre les deux prononciations, si bien que l'on peut ne pas savoir soi-même, tout en étant français, laquelle convient.

Le t est toujours prononcé dans « brut ».

Pour donner suite à  un [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36224/facteurs-dans-la-prononciation-de-but#comment72198_36224) j'ajoute que vu la quasi-régularité de la prononciation « [y] » pour les mots courants dans lesquels la terminaison « ut » induit le son « [y] », on est pratiquement en droit d'escompter « [y] » pour « brut » ; cela se vérifie dans la liste suivante, qui contient pratiquement  tous les mots de la catégorie considérée.

- *pas de son [t]* :   affut, ajut, attribut, bahut, bizut, canut, chalut, début, fût, institut, raffut, rebut, salut, statut, substitut, tribut,
- *son [t]* : brut, rut , ut , azimut, comput, occiput, scorbut, sinciput, uppercut,
- *les deux possibilités* : but, préciput,

Comment: Ton oreille est dérangée par */by/* mais pas pas l'expression *la liste suivante **qui consiste de pratiquement tous les mot** de la catégorie considérée* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Elle l'a été, une fois !

Comment: Je parlais de l'oreille, pas de l’œil... L'expression **qui consiste de** n'existe pas à ma connaissance en français bien qu'elle soit courante en espagnol *que consiste de* et en anglais *which consists of*. Une formule idiomatique pourrait être : *qui contient pratiquement...*

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, totalement inconscient de ça …